# setContentPane() and addActionListener gets a NullPointerException

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Form1 {
   private JPanel panel1;
   private JButton button1;


   public Form1() {
       button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
          @Override
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             System.out.println("Button clicked");
          }
       });
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
       JFrame frame = new JFrame("Form 1");
       frame.setContentPane(new Form1().panel1);
       frame.pack();
       frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The error relates to the `setContentPane` in main method and then also the `actionListener`. I've posted the exact error below. Why is this? I created this using the IntelliJ IDEA GUI form creator.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException  
    at Form1.<init>(Form1.java:12)  
    at Form1.main(Form1.java:22)
```

Comment: You did not initialize your panel1. I guess you wanted to create a panel1 and add the button1 (which is also not initialized) to it.

Comment: See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556) & [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/418556)

Answer (score 1):

In Java you can't use variables that are not initialized, else you will receive a NPE. See the following code and please read a Java book :)

```
public class Form1 {
   private JPanel panel1;
   private JButton button1;


   public Form1() {
      panel1 = new JPanel();
      button1 = new JButton1("Press Me");
      panel1.add(button1);
       button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
          @Override
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             System.out.println("Button clicked");
          }
       });
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
       JFrame frame = new JFrame("Form 1");
       frame.setContentPane(new Form1().panel1);
       frame.pack();
       frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So there are 2 issues that you're going to run into that are causing that error. After you create an object (`JButton`, `JPanel` in this case), you have to instantiate them. There are a lot of different ways to do this, and it depends on what you're trying to do, but the simplest fix for your issue here is to add the following lines in the constructor:

```
panel1 = new JPanel();
button1 = new JButton();
```

Your code should run fine after that.